# Sorting dictionary with tuple keys by specified element of tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dict, dict keys are tuples like: `(0,5)`

I want to sort the list by the value of the tuples[1].

I try with the key argument of method's list sort but i don't know what to put in the lambda i try this:
`key= lambda k[[1]]`

Sample input: `[{(5,9): "item"}, {(0,4): "item"}]`

Expected: `[{(0,4): "item"}, {(5,9): "item"}]`

Anyone could explain me how it works ?

Comment: Can you post a sample input/desired output/the code you have tried

Comment: input : [{(5,9): "item"}, {(0,4): "item"}]  output : [{(0,4): "item"}, {(5,9): "item"}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have something like this here is the solution:

```
a = [{(0,7): 1},
     {(1,5): 2},
     {(4,6): 3}]

sorted(a, key=lambda x: list(x.keys())[0][1])
#[{(1, 5): 2}, {(4, 6): 3}, {(0, 7): 1}]
```

Comment: I try your solution it gave me this : TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: It works thanks. but i did not understand why you add list() arround key() ?

Comment: In my opinion, better to use `next(iter(d.keys()))` to extract the only key of a dictionary.

Comment: @mg175430 That part transforms `dict_keys` object into `list` object that supports indexing.

Comment: @jpp Great idea, definite +1

Answer (score 3):

For a list of dictionaries, you can use:

```
lst = [{(5,9): "item"}, {(0,4): "item"}]

res = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: next(iter(x))[1])

[{(0, 4): 'item'}, {(5, 9): 'item'}]
```

The term `next(iter(x))` converts the dictionary keys into an iterator and then calls the first item. This works because each dictionary only has one key.

Note, as @juanpa.arrivillaga points out, there is no need to use `x.keys()` when iterating the keys of a dictionary, `iter(x)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
data=[{(5,9): "item"}, {(0,1): "item"},{(1,4): "item"}]

print(sorted(data,key=lambda x:list(map(lambda y:y[1],x.keys()))[0]))
```

output:

```
[{(0, 1): 'item'}, {(1, 4): 'item'}, {(5, 9): 'item'}]
```